# Getting directory names and writing them to a text file

Tags: batch-file

How to please store the names of the directories to C:\maindir\ to file C:\export.txt ?
Only directory, no files.

My directories

```
C:\maindir\dir1
C:\maindir\dir2
C:\maindir\dir3
```

export format file C:\export.txt

```
mytext dir1
mytext dir2
mytext dir3
```

Consult someone please ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can;

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad c:\maindir') do echo mytext %%a >> C:\temp\export.txt
```

(Note on recent versions of windows you cannot write to the root of C:)

Answer (score 0):

You must get the list of the files in a variable (say FILELIST) and then perform a loop:

```
for i in $FILELIST; do
    if [ -d $i ]; then
        echo $i >> c:\export.txt
    fi
done
```

This must do what you need.

Comment: I need a solution for windows, this is the Linux shell, right?

Comment: Oh, ok! Sorry! I'm not used to "think in Windows" anymore. Yes, this is Bash for Linux.